# How to increase the height of the clr-dg-action-overflow

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there a way to increase the height of the clr-dg-action-overflow item? Is setting the height of the `.action-item` class in the CSS sufficient? Does it affect other components?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to set a larger `line-height` on the `.action-item`. This would increase the space without affecting anything else.

```
.datagrid-action-overflow .action-item {
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```